# paginate through a category in a wordpress page.php template

Tags: wordpress, pagination, categories

I had originally set up my menu to set categories, but that limits my use of categories to the menu structure.

Ideally what I'd prefer to do is used page templates.

So I create a new page template 'page-for-cat.php' and name the template 'page of category'.

I add in this query to the page

```
<?php
query_posts('category_name=my-cat');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

I used this post as reference

I then make a new page in wordpress and set the page template to 'page of category'. I call the page 'Test page'.

I then add that 'Test Page' wordpress page to the menu structure.

So far, so good...

What I can't get to work is the pagination to previous and next pages to work with this set up.

Where am I going wrong, hav I missed something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

> **Note**: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

Here is a post I recently did on WPSE. This template lets you choose from a dropdown which category you want to display on the page. What is nice, you have one template for all pages, not one page template per category. Here is that page and post with pagination

From what I can understand is that you are specifically looking for a **page template** that you can set under page attributes in the page admin add/edit screen and auto assign a category to it.

Here is a page template that does exactly that. You can create a new page in the back end, assign this template to the page and then set a specific category to it, all from the back end.

**Here is how it work**

I have adapted this template from a tutorial by [digitalraindrops](http://digitalraindrops.net/2011/09/wordpress-twenty-eleven-a-page-of-posts/) that you can go and check out at the link provided. I have made a couple modifications to it to work on twentyfourteen. I have also removed the original [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) as it is used in a way that actually is the same as doing a normal [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) query, which should never be used.

> **Note:** This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when dealing with posts pagination).

*It should be noted before I start, you can also just create a proper category.php template, create a custom menu and add the required category to the menu. You should also note that you can use the category name as page slug, but you **cannot** have any child pages for these pages, this **will** interfere and break the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)*

To accomplish all of what we need, you need to create a custom meta box which will be added to the page add/edit screen when the specific template is selected. This meta box will be used to select which category will be used for the page selected. You will also be able to set custom `posts_per_page` and sort posts. Here is the code to add the custom meta box. Add these code to your functions.php or any functions related file

```
<?php
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  Add a post metabox with options to the admin page screen.
 *  After selcting the page-pop.php template as a page template,
 *  this metabox will appear in the admin page screen.
 *  From here you can choose which category's posts to display
 *  and how the posts will be displayed on the page
 *
 *  @package WordPress
 *  @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 *  @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  1. Only add meta boxes for the pop template
 *
 *  @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('admin_init', 'pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box');

function pietergoosen_add_pop_meta_box(){   
    $post_id = isset( $_GET['post'] ) ? $_GET['post'] : 0 ;
    if($post_id) { 
        $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
        if ($template_file == 'page-pop.php') { 
            add_meta_box('pop_meta_box', __( 'Page of Posts with the same name', 'pietergoosen' ), 'pietergoosen_pop_meta_options', 'page', 'side', 'core');
        } else {
            $meta = get_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', true);
            if( $meta ) {
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', '');
                pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', '');
                remove_meta_box( 'pop_meta_box', 'page', 'side' );
            }
        }
    }
    add_action('save_post', 'pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box');
}

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  2. Built the list to display the options in the metabox
 *
 *  @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$order_list = array(
    'none' => array( 'value' => 'none','label' => 'None' ),
    'id' => array( 'value' => 'ID','label' => 'Post ID' ),
    'author' => array( 'value' => 'author','label' => 'Author' ),
    'title' => array( 'value' => 'title','label' => 'Post Title' ),
    'date' => array( 'value' => 'date', 'label' => 'Post Date'  ),
    'modified' => array( 'value' => 'modified','label' => 'Modified Date' ),
    'parent' => array( 'value' => 'parent','label' => 'Parent Post' ),
    'rand' => array( 'value' => 'rand','label' => 'Random' ),
    'comment_count' => array( 'value' => 'comment_count','label' => 'Comment Count' ),
    'menu_order' => array( 'value' => 'menu_order','label' => 'Menu Order' ),
);

$sort = array(
    'DESC' => array( 'value' => 'DESC','label' => 'Descending' ),
    'ASC' => array( 'value' => 'ASC','label' => 'Ascending' ),
); 

function pietergoosen_pop_meta_options(){

    $post_id =  !empty($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : 0;
    if( !$post_id ) return;

    $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
    if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

    global $order_list,$post_styles,$sort;
    $categories = get_categories();

    //Check if we have values
    $post_meta=array();
    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id,false );

    $cat_id = isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
    $page_title = isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) && $post_meta['_page_title'] ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
    $posts_title = isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) && $post_meta['_posts_title'] ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
    $order_by = isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
    $asc = isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
    $post_count = isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');
    if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : '0';
    if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) $days = '0';
    ?>

    <!-- Sart the meta boxes -->
    <div class="inside">
    <p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Page Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p> 
    <input id="_posts_title" name="_posts_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $posts_title; ?>"/>  

    <p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Post Title', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p> 
    <input id="_page_title" name="_page_title" type="text" style="width: 98%;" value="<?php echo $page_title; ?>"/>

    <p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Category', 'pietergoosen' ); ?></strong></label></p>
    <select id="_cat_id" name="_cat_id">
<?php 
    //Category List
    foreach ($categories as $cat) :
        $selected = ( $cat->cat_ID == $cat_id ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
        $option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $cat->cat_ID;
        $option = $option .'">';
        $option = $option .$cat->cat_name;
        $option = $option .'</option>';
        echo $option;
    endforeach;
?>
    </select>

    <p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Sort by', 'pietergoosen' )?></strong></label></p>
    <select id="_order_by" name="_order_by">
<?php 
    foreach ($order_list as $output) :
        $selected = ( $output['value'] == $order_by ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
        $option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
        $option = $option .'">';
        $option = $option .$output['label'];
        $option = $option .'</option>';
        echo $option;
    endforeach;
?>
    </select>       

    <p><label><strong><?php _e( 'Order', 'pietergoosen' )?><strong></label></p>
    <select id="_asc" name="_asc">
<?php 
    foreach ($sort as $output) :
        $selected = ( $output['value'] == $asc ) ? ' selected = "selected" ' : '';
        $option = '<option '.$selected .'value="' . $output['value'];
        $option = $option .'">';
        $option = $option .$output['label'];
        $option = $option .'</option>';
        echo $option;
    endforeach;
?>
    </select>

    <p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts per Page', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
    <input id="_post_count" name="_post_count" type="text" value="<?php echo $post_count; ?>" size="3" />

    <p><strong><label><?php _e( 'Posts in the last days', 'pageofposts' ); ?><strong></label></p>
    <input id="_days" name="_days" type="text" value="<?php echo $days; ?>" size="3" />
    </div>
    <!-- End page of posts meta box -->
    <?php
}
function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta_box( $post_id ){

    if ( empty( $_POST ) ) {
        return;
    } else {
        $template_file = get_post_meta($post_id,'_wp_page_template',TRUE);
        if ($template_file != 'page-pop.php') return;

        if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        } else {
            if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'page' ) {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
                  return $post_id;
            } else {
                if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
                  return $post_id;
            }
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_cat_id'] ) ? $_POST['_cat_id'] : 1;         
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_cat_id', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_page_title'] ) ? $_POST['_page_title'] : '';            
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_page_title', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_posts_title'] ) ? $_POST['_posts_title'] : '';          
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_posts_title', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_order_by'] ) ? $_POST['_order_by'] : 'date';            
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_order_by', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_asc'] ) ? $_POST['_asc'] : 'DESC';
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_asc', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_post_count'] ) ? $_POST['_post_count'] : get_option('posts_per_page');
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_post_count', $meta);
            $meta = isset( $_POST['_days'] ) ? $_POST['_days'] : 0;
            pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, '_days', $meta);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function pietergoosen_pop_update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data) {
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
    if( $data != '' && $post_meta != $data) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $data);
    } elseif ( $post_meta != '' && $data == '' ) {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $key);
    }
}
?>
```

Now for the page template. Create a file in your root directory and call it `page-pop.php`. You have to call your template this. If you need to rename it, check in the code above and change all instances of `page-pop.php` to the template name of your choice

The first section will call back all the saved values from the meta box. These values will be fed back into your custom `WP_Query` to call back all the posts according to category.

The first loop is your normal page template loop which you can use to display content added to the WYSIWYG editor in the page add/edit screen. The second loop/query is the query that will return your posts. You should note that all markup here is for the default twenty fourteen theme, you will need to modify it to suite your theme.

Here is the code that should go into your `page-pop.php` template

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Page of Posts
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
    //See if we have any values
    $post_meta          =   array();
    $post_meta          =   get_post_meta( $post->ID,false );
    $catid              =   isset( $post_meta['_cat_id'] ) ? $post_meta['_cat_id'][0] : 1;
    $page_title         =   isset( $post_meta['_page_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_page_title'][0] : '';
    $posts_title        =   isset( $post_meta['_posts_title'] ) ? $post_meta['_posts_title'][0] : '';
    $orderby            =   isset( $post_meta['_order_by'] ) ? $post_meta['_order_by'][0] : 'date';
    $asc                =   isset( $post_meta['_asc'] ) ? $post_meta['_asc'][0] : 'DESC';
    $list_style         =   isset( $post_meta['_list_style'] ) ? $post_meta['_list_style'][0] : 'default';  
    $post_count         =   isset( $post_meta['_post_count'] ) ? $post_meta['_post_count'][0] : get_option('posts_per_page');

    if(!$post_count || !is_numeric( $post_count )) 
        $post_count = get_option('posts_per_page');
    $days = isset( $post_meta['_days'] ) ? $post_meta['_days'][0] : 0;
    if($days && !is_numeric( $days )) 
        $days = 0;
    $do_not_show_stickies = ($list_style == 'default') ? 0 : 1;
?>  

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

    <!-- Page Title -->
    <?php if( $posts_title ) : ?>
        <article id="posts-title">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo $posts_title; ?></h2>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        </article><!-- #posts-title -->
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php the_post(); ?>
        <?php global $post;
        if( $post->post_content || $page_title ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <?php if( $page_title ) : ?>
                    <header class="entry-header">
                        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>
                    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( $post->post_content ) : ?>    
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <footer class="entry-meta">

                </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <?php endif; ?>
            </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
        </div>  
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php 

/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  Start our custom query to display category posts
 *
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/   
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = array( 
            'cat'                   => $catid,
            'posts_per_page'        => $post_count,
            'paged'                 => $paged,
            'orderby'               => $orderby,
            'order'                 => $asc,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => $do_not_show_stickies,
        );

        if( $days ) {
            function pop_filter_where( $where = '') {
                global $days;
                    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-' .$days .' days')) . "'";
                return $where;
            }
            add_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );

            $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);
            remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'pop_filter_where' );

        } else {

            $cat_query = new WP_Query($args);

        }           
        // Output
        if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :

            $counter = 1; //Starts counter for post column lay out

            // Start the Loop.
            while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post(); ?>

                <div class="entry-column<?php echo ( $counter%2  ? ' left' : ' right' ); ?>">

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                </div>  

                <?php   

                $counter++; //Update the counter

            endwhile;

                // next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
                next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $cat_query->max_num_pages );
                previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); 

                wp_reset_postdata();

            else : 

                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif; ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php get_sidebar( 'content' ); ?>

</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

I hope I understood you correctly and hope this is what you need